# What Voltage rating for DC-blocking capacitor between circuit stages in microphone preamp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, dc

What DC rating should I pick for DC-blocking caps between 2 stages of an audio circuit using opamps (5532) operated on +16/-16v rails.

Is it about the AC voltage that will pass through it that can go as high as 26 Vpp or about the DC voltage that I read can leak out of an opamp but I was barely able to measure (+- 10mV).

Here is the circuit:[image]

I've seen, 10v cap rating, even 6.3v. I guess it's about what is called DC bias or something? Also, I'v always seen the + side of caps looking at the output of the preceding opamp stage, is it always how it should be?

Thanks

Comment: For what you say, AC voltage is the largest one, so 13 Vpk would require a 16 Vdc cap. However, if it happens that you might have higher DC component, you need larger rating. The extreme case is the max voltage in your circuit, 32 Vdc of supply: this rule "never fails". So, 25 V for the former, 35 V for the latter. If space is a problem, you tradeoff. Current is not an issue here.

Comment: Transformer does input DC blocking; the 'next stage' load is unknown, so the coupling impedance is indeterminate.   Except for the op amp offset error, there's NO DC to be blocked!

Comment: Thanks Whit3rd.  The next stage is another (switchable)  identical opamp config with a fixed 10 db gain, then a switchable inverter opamp (for phase reverse)  with no gain Rin = Rfb= 5k1. All have the same 100uf cap with 47K res after the opamp. You raise the question I was asking myself: I can barely measure (+- 7 to 25 mV) any DC out in this circuit so why put DC blocking caps at all?